# Where can i find Visual Basic Image Internal Structure Format by Alex Ionescu?

Tags: patch-reversing, visual-basic

Where i can find a working link to this tutorial? I have searched a lot on the net but all links are broken. Could anyone upload it somewhere?

Original link
http://www.alex-ionescu.com/vb.pdf

Comment: Ever heard of [the Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/)? It's there. As is (presumably) everything else.

Comment: Sorry i don't know that website. What's wrong with asking? why negative thumb? Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/vb.pdf (and thank you for not assuming this was me downvoting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20071020232030/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/vb.pdf

[more chars ftw][more chars ftw]